# I want to add a specific jquery show effect, but I am unable to get the code right

Tags: jquery

I actually wanted to incorporate the "drop" named effect shown in the demo below in the given link.

http://jqueryui.com/show/

I wanted to add that effect to 2 single elements which would show on both sides of a central image on clicking a button in the centre of the page. This is the page where I wanted to add such an effect :

http://iwarchitects.com

I want the "Projects" and "Company" headings to drop out on the left and right sides when you press the central IWA button.

here's the HTML code :

```
<div id="iwabutton">
<img src="siteimages/iwabutton.png" height="110px" width="110px">
</div>

 <div class="leftcontainer">
      <div class="projects">
          <p id="projectstext"> <h2>PROJECTS</h2> </p>
      </div>
      <div class="company">
          <p id="projectstext"> <h2>COMPANY</h2> </p>
      </div>
 </div>
```

please help me add that effect into my page. I understood the usage of .show() function, but i am making some mistake which iam unable to understand

Comment: Post your code here, we`ll help u out & also specify whats the problem

Comment: You'll need to include the jquery and jqueryUI libraries (in that order) on your html page

Comment: Click on view source link to see how the demo is done.

Comment: I understood the show function, but how to get the two headings to pop out on the left and right in a single click?

Answer (score 0):

if you had clicked "view source" on that page you could see how they use the `.show` method

```
 $( "#effect" ).show( "scale", { percent: 100 }/*options for the effect*/, 500, callback/*optional*/ );
 $( "#effect" ).show( "bounce", { }, 500, callback );
 $( "#effect" ).show( "blind", { }, 500, callback );
```

where `#effect` is the id of the element, or you could use the class name if you want to select the elements to do the effect on has that class name like `effectclass`

```
$( ".effectclass" ).show( "blind", { }, 500, callback );
```